# SharePoint Online: Embeded pdf files are displayed in a poor quality

Tags: sharepoint-online, pdf, word-pdf

What is the best way to embed PDF files which are stored in SharePoint document libraries into third party web site pages hosted on third party domain? We tried to use WopiFrame2.aspx and it works but quality is bad. Native browser viewer is not an option because of Content Security Policies headers. Is there any good modern way how to embed SharePoint PDF files on third party domain ?

Comment: Are you looking for free to use solutions only? Or are you open to paid commercial solutions?

Comment: I think we are looking for good way to do it using O365/SharePoint way. WopiFrame2 is supported solution. so it is a question why it shows so low quality of PDF files